# Scroll feature of listview within scroll view

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

In my application within a scroll view, I am using list view. But the list view is not scrolling. Can anyone suggest me what should i do.
I searched for it and find out that the **list view don't scroll within scroll view**.
Any solution?

Comment: any special reasons for adding a scrollview to already scroll enabled listview?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own list view and set expand to false. Here is the sample class

```
public class ExpandableHeightListView extends ListView {

boolean expanded = false;

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ExpandableHeightListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
        int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public boolean isExpanded() {
    return expanded;
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    // HACK! TAKE THAT ANDROID!
    if (isExpanded()) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
        params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
    this.expanded = expanded;
}
 }
```

You can use like this your activity.clas

```
 ExpandableHeightListView listview = (ExpandableHeightListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listview.setExpanded(true);
```

In your layout file you can use ExpandableHeightListView at the place of list view within a scroll view. It will scroll.

Comment: What's the point of using a ListView if you allow no items recycling ? Better use a vertical LinearLayout then.

Answer (score 5):

Exclude ListView from ScrollView, because ListView already have scrolling mechanism in it.

Comment: Its like a form so i can not exclude the listView from the scroll view.

Comment: I Dont Know why Running away from the problem solution gets the maximum votes :P

Comment: @IronManGill jealous? :P

Comment: @ArfanMirza Why wud i be kiddo ?? Im way past earning rep points :P ... Im just suggesting you shudnt run from the problem...

Comment: I am not suggest to run from problem, rather i want the bug to be avoided to start with...

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a listview inside a scrollview.

The listview already handles scrolling so it doesn't need to be inside a scrollview.

You should change your layouts to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

ListView Inside Scroll View will not work . Put it out side of that . Because both have scrolling feature so scroll will not work when thay will come together .

Answer (score 1):

Use this Class.

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {
    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in your xml layout change your scrollview tag with the package name and class of the CustomScrollView. i.e. change  to **com.test.CustomScrollView**.

And inside you Activity get the id of the custom scroll view and include this code.

```
private int currentX, currentY;
private CustomScrollView customScrollView;

customScrollView.setSmoothScrollingEnabled(true);
customScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            currentX = (int) event.getRawX();
            currentY = (int) event.getRawY();
            break;
        }
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                int x2 = (int) event.getRawX();
                int y2 = (int) event.getRawY();
                customScrollView.scrollBy(0 , currentY - y2);
                currentY = y2;
                break;
            }   
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a listView inside a ScrollView.
You should read the Romain Guy answer and the comment above:

[How can I put a ListView into a ScrollView without it collapsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing)

You can exclude ListView from Scroll view.
If you would like to have a "list" inside a scrollView you could use a LinearLayout. Something like this:

```
public class MyListLayout extends LinearLayout implements
        View.OnClickListener {

    private Adapter list;
    private View.OnClickListener mListener;

    public MyListLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }

    public EvernoteListLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mListener!=null)
            mListener.onClick(v);
    }

    public void setList(Adapter list) {
        this.list = list;

        //Popolute list
        if (this.list!=null){
            for (int i=0;i<this.list.getCount();i++){
                View item= list.getView(i, null,null);
                this.addView(item);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setmListener(View.OnClickListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }
}



// Create ArrayAdapter
 MyListAdapter mListAdapter = new MyListAdapter();
 MyListLayout mLay = (MyListLayout) findViewById(R.id.box_list_ev);
 if (mLay != null) {
        mLay.setList(mListAdapter);
 }
```

Comment: so we just have to put `Mylistlayout` will work like listview?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyListView extends ListView {

    public MyListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyListView(Context context, android.util.AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);
    }
}
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

The scroll view "eats" all the touches...
You should avoid inserting a scrolling element (ListView) into another scrolling element(scroll view), your user could go crazy.

In these cases I use a LinearLayout in place of the ListView and I inflate into it the customview created to represent each List element, here is an example, fell free to ask me more:

```
LinearLayout containerLinearLayout=    (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.containerLinearLayout);
containerLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
JSONObject convocazione=array.getJSONObject(i);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_element_layout,null);
TextView txtDettaglioLuogo=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.txtDettaglioLuogo);
TextView txtOra=(TextView)child.findViewById(R.id.txtOra);


txtOra.setText("text");
txtData.setText("more text");


containerLinearLayout.addView(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution for the scrolling issue i got custom scrollview class to manage the scrollview.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class VerticalScrollview extends ScrollView{

public VerticalScrollview(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

 public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalScrollview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action)
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: DOWN super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                return false; // redirect MotionEvents to ourself

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: CANCEL super false" );
                super.onTouchEvent(ev);
                break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: UP super false" );
                return false;

        default: Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + action ); break;
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    Log.i("VerticalScrollview", "onTouchEvent. action: " + ev.getAction() );
     return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the onMeasure source code of the ListView, you will find that if the height measureSpec is UNSPECIFIED then the height of the listview is the height of only one item plus some padding, see below:

```
 if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
        heightSize = mListPadding.top + mListPadding.bottom + childHeight +
                getVerticalFadingEdgeLength() * 2;
    }
```

---

So we can simplily change the height SpecMode to AT_MOST, and the height size is the left height size of its parent. 
Below is the solution:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), 
            MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.